# Create Multi Line Edit Text and Scrolling the activity View

Tags: android, xml

**I'm trying to create multi line edit text and typing on it , but when the pointer is down and down on screen ..  I can't see my written text .. it's going behind the keyboard .. **

```
<android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
            android:id="@+id/input_layout_details"
            android:layout_width="326dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_below="@+id/textView2"
            android:layout_marginTop="18dp"
            android:textColorHint="#6c6c6c"
            app:hintTextAppearance="@style/HintXlarge"
            android:layout_weight="0.97">

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/input_details"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:hint="@string/hint_Details"
                android:inputType="textMultiLine"
                android:selectAllOnFocus="false"
                android:textColor="@android:color/background_light"
                android:textColorHint="#6c6c6c"
                android:textIsSelectable="false"
                android:textSize="30sp"
                android:theme="@style/Widget.App.EditText"/>
        </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put the whole body inside ScrollView.

```
    <ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/scrollFView"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:fillViewport="true"
android:scrollbars="vertical">

<android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
    android:id="@+id/input_layout_details"
    android:layout_width="326dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_marginTop="18dp"
    android:textColorHint="#6c6c6c"
    app:hintTextAppearance="@style/HintXlarge"
    android:layout_weight="0.97">

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/input_details"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:hint="@string/hint_Details"
        android:inputType="textMultiLine"
        android:selectAllOnFocus="false"
        android:textColor="@android:color/background_light"
        android:textColorHint="#6c6c6c"
        android:textIsSelectable="false"
        android:textSize="30sp"
        android:theme="@style/Widget.App.EditText" />
</android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Answer (score 0):

set the value of the scrollbars = vertical in the edit text body.
android:scrollbars="vertical"

Comment: Not this what I need ,, I'm trying to scroll all activity without scrolling the text